# Can't use pdflatex in textmate since 2.0-beta.6.8

Tags: errors, pdftex, textmate

Here is the temp.tex :

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}
TEST
\end{document}
```

and the temp.log :

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2014)
(preloaded format=pdflatex 2014.6.30)  16 FEB 2015 21:58 entering
extended mode  \write18 enabled.  file:line:error style messages
enabled.  %&-line parsing enabled.
**temp.tex (./temp.tex LaTeX2e <2014/05/01> Babel <3.9k> and hyphenation patterns for 78 languages loaded.

! LaTeX Error: File `article.cls' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed, or enter new name. (Default
extension: cls)

Enter file name:  ./temp.tex:2: Emergency stop. <read *> 
          l.2 ^^M

*** (cannot \read from terminal in nonstop modes)

  Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:  10 strings out of 493117
172 string characters out of 6135433  52909 words of memory out of
5000000  3571 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000  3640
words of font info for 14 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000  1141
hyphenation exceptions out of 8191  10i,0n,7p,43b,8s stack positions
out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s ./temp.tex:2:  ==> Fatal error
occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

a command line in the terminal do the job.

How solve the problem?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Does it work if you call pdflatex on the cmdline?

Comment: Yes, it does. It seems path is not set textmate, although indicated in preference panel.

Answer (score 1):

I had a personal path configuration in the preferences options. In removing these variables, everything is back in order.